# How to write list of a dictionary as csv

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary, in which for each key exists lists of (possible empty) lists.
Now I want to write them in a csv file.

Dictionary:

```
d = {'A' : [['a', 'b'], ['a', 't', 'c']],[[],['a','b']]
     'B' : [['c', 'd'], ['e']],[['f', 'g'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]}
```

Furthermore I know that the first list of 'A' is related to the first list of 'B', the second of 'A' to the  second of 'B' and so on.
Wished Output:
csv file looking like:

```
A , B 
a , c
b , d

a , e
t ,
c , 

  , f
  , g

a , c
b , d
  , e
```

All I tried so far was super "inconvenient" and didn't work in the end.

Comment: Is it possible to use another, better suited, format for your output file? Like JSON

Comment: Please correct your `Dic` variable, it's not a valid python dict.

Comment: I edited the dictionary variable.
@CHURLZ Unfortunaly I need a csv for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified you Dic variable to look like this so that it is valid:

```
d = {'A' : [['a', 'b'], ['a', 't', 'c'],[],['a','b']],
     'B' : [['c', 'd'], ['e'],['f', 'g'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]}
```

The following code will do the pair wise matching you want over the elements of the list in each dict entry.

```
import itertools

with open('file.csv', 'w') as fid:            
    fid.write("{} , {}\n".format(*d.keys()))
    # first let's iterate over the element in the lists in d['a'] and d['b']
    # A and B will be matched sublists
    for A, B in itertools.zip_longest(d['A'],d['B'], fillvalue=''):
        # next iterate over the elements in the sub lists.  
        # Each pair will be an entry you want to write to your file
        for pair in itertools.zip_longest(A, B, fillvalue=''):                        
            fid.write("{} , {}\n".format(*pair))
        fid.write('\n')
```

[zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) is the magic sauce here.  It does the pair wise matching that you want.  It will terminate when the end of the longest list is reached (as opposed to just `zip` which will terminates when the end of the shortest list is reached.

Content of file.csv:

```
A , B
a , c
b , d

a , e
t , 
c , 

 , f
 , g

a , c
b , d
 , e
```

Comment: Thank you,
I didn't know the zip_longest so far.
Also appreciate the comments in the code!

Answer (score 0):

A hand made solution, with pure python tools :

```
Dic = {'A' : [['a', 'b'], ['a', 't', 'c'],[],['a','b']],
       'B' : [['c', 'd'], ['e'],['f', 'g'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]}


with open('out.csv','w') as f:
    print(*Dic,sep=',',file=f) # keys
    for A,B in zip(*Dic.values()):
        for i in range(max(len(A),len(B))):
            print(A[i] if i<len(A) else ' ',end=',',file=f) 
            print(B[i] if i<len(B) else ' ',        file=f) 
        print(file=f) # blank line
```

For

```
A,B
a,c
b,d

a,e
t, 
c, 

 ,f
 ,g

a,c
b,d
 ,e
```